# AngularJS formData without ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have what possibly is a bizarre situation: 
i have a form that edit/updates informations from different objects (as services).

What i'm trying to achieve is: i wanna use ng-model to link the input fields to the relative objects BUT upon form submission i wanna get a formData object to send via POST. Problem is: how do i convert Angular's Form object into a formData one? I don't mean looping or boring stuff, anybody did that before?

HTML

```
<form name="Ctrl.form" ng-submit="Ctrl.submit()" ng-controller="MyController as Ctrl">
   <input type="text" name="full_name" ng-model="Ctrl.user.fullName">
   <input type="text" name="cart_total" ng-model="Ctrl.cart.gross_total">
   <input type="city" name="city" ng-model="Ctrl.dropship.city">
</form>
```

Controller

```
this.user = User.getData();
this.cart = Cart.get();
this.dropship = User.addressBook.getDropShip();

this.submit = function() {
   // transform this.form into formData
}
```

does it make any sense? Am i missing something?

Thanks!
Yours truly

Edit: the form encompasses (gathers informations from) multiple objects, but not all of their properties can be POSTed. I hope this makes more sense

Answer (score 0):

You already have a user object that is bound to the form's input fields - just pass it to your submit function:

HTML

```
<form name="Ctrl.form" ng-submit="Ctrl.submit(Ctrl.user)" ng-controller="MyController as Ctrl">
   <input type="text" name="full_name" ng-model="Ctrl.user.fullName">
</form>
```

Controller

```
this.user = User.getData();
this.submit = function(user) {
     $http({ method:'POST', url: 'AddUser', data: user })
        .success(function() {
             ...
        });       
}
```

Comment: Good point! lack of explanation on my end. The form encompasses multiple objects and some properties must not be sent.

Answer (score 0):

When put object in javascript function as parameter you pass it thru reference, so an object in service you get is not a copy, but an adress of this object, so every operation are bind to the view. This will allow re-use service for multiple views

Comment: Ehm... Yes. I am slowly realising that sounded like a super N00b question? :)